# Annotate Min value of filtered related Model

Tags: django

I have a Track Model and these tracks have a weekly rank in different charts (charttype)

```
class Track(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField('Unique ID', max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField('Track title', max_length=100)
    ...


class Rank(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    trackid = models.ForeignKey(Track, related_name='rank')
    pos = models.PositiveIntegerField("Position", blank=True, null=True)
    charttype= models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHARTTYPE)
    ...
```

I first query for a specific charttype:

```
track_list_top100 = Track.objects.filter(rank__charttype='total')
```

after that I want to annotate this QuerySet with the highest position for that track for that specific charttype:

```
track_list_top100 = track_list_top100.annotate(highestpos=Min('rank__pos'))
```

But what I get is the highestposition for all charts combined. In other words the filter that I've set in the first query `filter(rank__charttype='total')` is not used in the annotation.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should return the smallest `pos` for the related `Rank`s. Can you print the query it generates (with `print(str(track_list_top100 .query))`).

Comment: `SELECT 'charts_track'.'id', 'charts_track'.'title', MIN('charts_rank'.'pos') AS 'highestpos' FROM 'charts_track' INNER JOIN 'charts_rank' ON ('charts_track'.'id' = 'charts_rank'.'trackid_id') WHERE 'charts_rank'.'charttype' = total GROUP BY 'charts_track'.'id' ORDER BY NULL`

Comment: Then this should use the minimum of the `total` `Rank`s.

Comment: Yes ... that is the result now. But I need the minimum of the ranks with charttype = total

Comment: Well that is what I mean. Can you provide a (sample) dataset where it does not work? I really doubt it does not work. It filters the `Rank`s such that the type is `'total'` both in the Django ORM and SQL query.

Comment: Thanx Willem! Seeing the actually query now helps me a lot. I will tinker a bit and see if a can reduce a sample set from the huge date set.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I found it: 

In the question I simplified the initial query. The real query was:

`track_list_top100 = Track.objects.filter(rank__pos__lte=1000, rank__charttype='total', Q(mainartist__originalname__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))`

Mixing up Q objects in the filter was the problem. Apperently it should be all Q objects. Like:
 
`filter(Q(rank__pos__lte=1000), Q(rank__charttype='total'), Q(mainartist__originalname__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))`
Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

In django `>= 2.0` this could be achieved with

```
track_list_top100 = track_list_top100.annotate(
    highestpos=Min('rank__pos', filter=Q(rank__charttype='total'))
)
```

For more info read docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations